# How to write to the vertex colors for each frame like animation

Tags: python, vertex-paint

How to write to the vertex colors for each frame
ie. Is there a way to assign color to a loop index for each frame and that data should be available to the dependency graph.
Is this possible with bpy? baking physics button does this job I gues, maybe C code. any help in this direction ?